# Changing inspector value with script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got some prefabs that move in a certain speed. All have the same script where that speed is assigned from the value of a public variable in the inspector. Like this:
[image]

The variable is Object Speed. What I want to do is changing this speed for every component that uses the script Movimiento Objeto.
My question is: how can I change this value for every component? Probably it's something related to `GetComponent` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you want the GameObjects to all have different random speeds?  Or are you looking to change the speed to a specific value at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

If you spawn your objects by your code, you can put them to *List* and manipulate them through list.

If you put some or all of these objects at the start of the program on the scene manualy, you can do as Sharundaar said (use *GetComponentsInChildren()*) and put them in list if you will spawn more of them at runtime, or put them into simple array *MovimientoObjecto[]*.

Using list will help you if you wish to add more of these prefabs at runtime (after your program started and do it by code).

Comment: Yes probably list is the way to go because like you said I spawn objects by my code. But I'm not quite sure where I should be creating this list, in which script (Movimiento Objeto or another)? And how do I change Object Speed value of the objects in my list?

Comment: I would recommend you to create other class, which would have this list of your MovimientoObjecto classes. This class should have function, which would be put into your Main class update() function, so you could manipulate your MovimientoObjecto object every frame. In the class, where your list is, you could add new MovimientoObjecto to list by `MovimientoObjecto mo = new MovimientoObjecto(); MovimientoObjectoList.Add(mo);` Or you could change speed `MovimientoObjectoList[n].ObjectSpeed = someFloat;` .If you don't understand something, tell that in the comments, I'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your objects as child of an other object, then add the script that wants to change your variable to the parent you just created, then you can call *GetComponentsInChildren< MovimientoObjecto >();* to get all the children that have this component, finally you iterate through it to change the variable.

For exemple :

```c#
public class MyClass : MonoBehavior
{
    MovimientoObjecto[] m_objects;

    void Start()
    {
        m_objects = GetComponentsInChildren<MovimientoObjecto>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach(MovimientoObjecto obj in m_objects)
        {
            obj.objectSpeed = // something
        }
    }
}
```

See : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html